# ActionBar Not Showing Up

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme

I am new to android development.I wanted to customise my app theme.So for that i have created a custom style.In my theme i want the colour of action bar to be different.I tried doing it but i my action bar is not visible.Please do help me out.
Code

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>


    <style name="HsJobTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>


    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#ffcdc434</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: Use `AppCompat` not `Holo`. Your Main`Activity` needs to extend `ActionBarActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
ActionBar actionBar=getActionBar();
```

Then use:

```
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(R.style.MyActionBar);
```

Comment: But i am setting the theme in manifest still m not getting it

Comment: Hope you are using ActionBar Activities!

Comment: I am using normal Activity

Comment: try to extend your activity class to ActionBarActivity. For Eg: public class LoginAuth extends ActionBarActivity

Answer (score 0):

Create a layout like `custom_actionbar.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="50dp"
 android:background="@drawable/black_pattern" >

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:margin="5dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In your activity in `onCreate()` , do like this..

```
    ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);
    TextView mTitleTextView = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
    mTitleTextView.setText("My Own Title");
    mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

its work for me

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main1" />
```

1-set color-> android:background="#code color"
not forget 
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
}
2-use android studio
 or use this code

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable("COLOR"));
```